# android - get pivot point of an ImageView for API < 11

Tags: android, user-interface, coordinates

suppose `imgv` is an `ImageView`

if I say float `x = imgv.getPivotX(); float y = imgv.getPivotY();`
this will give me the pivot point, however, this requires your app to target api 11 and above, I want to do the same for api 8, what function should I use?

Answer (score 1):

Pivot is related to animations. To make them compatible with Android 1.0+ you should use [NineOldAndroids](http://nineoldandroids.com/)

Then you can use the helper class: `float x = ViewHelper.getPivotX(imgv);`

Comment: So I download the library and then even if I say `float x = imgv.getPivotX();` it will make .apk compatible for Android 1.0+?

Comment: The library ports all the functionality, but the usage is slightly different. See the usage/samples